# Is there a command to make csh re-read all the directories in your path on FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, csh

I am having a weird issue in FreeBSD9 using `csh` as my shell. Newly installed programs that are in my path will only launch if I relaunch the `csh` shell. I find this really annoying.

I guess `csh` searches paths once and doesn't re-search them until you exit it. How do you force it to update itself? Is there something you can put in the `.cshrc` to make it stop doing this? (I'm used to bash, and I don't see anything like this going on in bash.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Unix C shell hashes your search path directories to help it find executables faster.  But it develops blind spots if you add new executables to those directories after it's already done its hash.  The solution is to use the `rehash` command to tell it to rebuild its hash.  Alternately, you can turn off the path hash entirely (taking a slight performance hit) using the `unhash` command.

(Fwiw, I agree this is annoying behavior.  I use a path hash in my own [Hamilton C shell](http://hamiltonlabs.com/Cshell.htm), but mine is smart enough to discover blind spots and repair them automatically.)

Comment: It surprises me that each instance of the shell has its own hash. I guess each shell MIGHT have its own different path, even if the same .cshrc created the initial path, so I guess that's inevitable.

Comment: The hash is created in memory by each instance of the C shell as it scans the path directories.  Bear in mind that every process gets its own copy of the environment variables (including PATH) and can change them without affecting other processes.

Comment: I remember reading an article about your shell in DDJ, in the early 1990s. I think it was this one: http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/examining-the-hamilton-c-shell/184408480  OS/2... Wow. Memories.

Comment: Yup, that's my C shell.  I had a different first name then but that's me.  Who knew that 25 years later I'd still be working on it, still adding features and support for new releases of Windows.

Comment: Nice!  I tried the x64 demo version on Win8 RTM just now. I am happy to report it seems to run just fine.   Some feedback: I miss having "man" when running in this environment, as compared to cygwin.  I can't get far in BSD-like shell environments without man.  And ssh. And this thermos, and this paddle-ball game. And that's ALL I need.  :-)

Comment: I'm glad you're enjoying it.  All the utilities have online help with `-h`.  If you still prefer `man`, try `alias man (^!^!:^^ -h | mi)`. You can also press F1 to open up the hypertext user guide in your browser.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a current version of `tcsh` (I currently have `tcsh 6.20.00 (Astron) 2016-11-24`), you can `set autorehash` (e.g. in your `~/.cshrc` or at prompt) to enable automatically rescan of `path' directories if need to (like bash). Per the tcsh man page:

```
  autorehash (+)
     If set, the internal hash table of the contents of the directories in the
     path variable will be recomputed if a command is not found in the hash table.  
     In addition, the list of available commands will be rebuilt for each command
     completion or spelling correction attempt if set to `complete' or `correct' 
     respectively;  if set to `always', this will be done for both cases.
```

Although, there are some edge cases, as noted in the `rehash` command section of the tcsh man page:

```
rehash  Causes the internal hash table of the contents of the directories
        in the path variable to be recomputed.
        ...
        With autorehash, a new command will be found automatically, except
        in the special case where another command of the same name
        which is located in a different directory already exists in the
        hash table.  Also flushes the cache of home  directories built
        by tilde expansion.
```